# using $Partition function to improve query performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, partitioning, query-performance

I have tables which are partitioned based on a `INT` column.

I see some queries that are using `$Partition` function to compare partition number instead of comparing the actual field data.

For example instead of saying:

```
select *
from T1 
    inner join T2 on T2.SnapshotKey = T1.SnapshotKey
```

they have been written like below:

```
select *
from T1 
    inner join T2 on $Partition.PF_Name(T2.SnapshotKey) = $Partition.PF_Name(T1.SnapshotKey)
```

where `PF_Name` is the name of partition function.

I see comments on those queries that this has been done to improve performance, and when I run both queries I see different in execution time and different execution plan. I'm not sure how these two queries are different.

This is a real query:

```
-- this takes about 9 seconds 
select sum(PrinBal)
from fpc
    inner join gl on gl.SnapshotKey = fpc.SnapshotKey
where fpc.SnapshotKey = 201703

-- this takes about 5 seconds
select sum(PrinBal)
from fpc
    inner join gl on $Partition.SnapshotKeyPF(gl.SnapshotKey) = $Partition.SnapshotKeyPF(fpc.SnapshotKey)
where fpc.SnapshotKey = 201703
```

And below is the execution plan of the real query:

[image: You can see the execution plan here]

Sorry I can't upload even a sanitized execution plan as uploads are monitored by our network and it might be a policy violation.

Question is: Why execution plans are different and why the second query is faster.

I appreciate if someone can share any idea on this. Just interested to know why they are different. Faster is better though.

**This is happening on SQL Server 2014. If I run the same on SQL Server 2012, the result will be different and the first query will perform faster!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why execution plans are different

#### First query

```
select sum(PrinBal)
from fpc
    inner join gl on gl.SnapshotKey = fpc.SnapshotKey
where fpc.SnapshotKey = 201703
```

The optimizer knows:

- `gl.SnapshotKey = fpc.SnapshotKey`; and
- `fpc.SnapshotKey = 201703`

so it can infer:

- `gl.SnapshotKey = 201703`

Just as if you had written:

```
select sum(PrinBal)
from fpc
    inner join gl on gl.SnapshotKey = fpc.SnapshotKey
where fpc.SnapshotKey = 201703
and gl.SnapshotKey = 201703
```

The literal value 201703 can also be used by the optimizer to determine the partition id. With both `SnapshotKey` predicates (one given, one inferred) this means the optimizer knows the partition id for both tables.

Going further, with a literal value (201703) for `SnapshotKey` now available on both tables, the join predicate:

- `gl.SnapshotKey = fpc.SnapshotKey`

simplifies to:

- `201703 = 201703`; or simply
- `true`

Meaning there is no join predicate at all. The result is a logical cross join. Expressing the final execution plan using the closest available T-SQL syntax, it is as if you wrote:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(Q1.c) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE SUM(Q1.s)
    END
FROM 
(
    SELECT c = COUNT_BIG(*), s = SUM(GL.PrinBal)
    FROM dbo.gl AS GL
    WHERE GL.SnapshotKey = 201703
    AND $PARTITION.PF(GL.SnapshotKey) = $PARTITION.PF(201703)
) AS Q1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT Dummy = 1
    FROM dbo.fpc AS FPC
    WHERE FPC.SnapshotKey = 201703
    AND $PARTITION.PF(FPC.SnapshotKey) = $PARTITION.PF(201703)
) AS Q2;
```

#### Second query

```
select sum(PrinBal)
from fpc
    inner join gl on $Partition.PF(gl.SnapshotKey) = $Partition.PF(fpc.SnapshotKey)
where fpc.SnapshotKey = 201703
```

The optimizer can no longer infer anything about `gl.SnapshotKey`, so the simplifications and transformations made for the first query are no longer possible.

Indeed, unless it is true that each partition holds only a single `SnapshotKey`, the rewrite is not guaranteed to produce the same results.

Again, expressing the execution plan produced using the closest available T-SQL syntax:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(Q2.c) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE SUM(Q2.s)
    END
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        Q1.PtnID,
        c = COUNT_BIG(*),
        s = SUM(Q1.PrinBal)
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT GL.PrinBal, PtnID = $PARTITION.PF(GL.SnapshotKey)
        FROM dbo.gl AS GL
    ) AS Q1
    GROUP BY
        Q1.PtnID
) AS Q2
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT Dummy = 1
    FROM dbo.fpc AS FPC
    WHERE
        $PARTITION.PF(FPC.SnapshotKey) = Q2.PtnID
        AND FPC.SnapshotKey = 201703
) AS Q3;
```

This time there is no logical cross join. Instead, there is a correlated join (an apply) on the partition id.

---

> why the second query is faster.

This is hard to assess from the information given. Using mock data and tables based on the queries and plan image provided, I found the first query outperformed the second in every case.

The same query expressed using different syntax can often produce a different execution plan, simply because the optimizer started from a different point, and explored options in a different order before it found a suitable execution plan. Plan search is not exhaustive, and not every possible logical transformation is available, so the end result is likely to be different. As noted above, the two queries do not necessarily express the same requirement anyway (at least given the information available to the optimizer).

On a separate note, be aware that the initial columnstore implementation in SQL Server 2012 (and to a somewhat lesser extent, 2014) has many limitations, not least on the optimization side of things. You will likely get better, and more consistent, results by upgrading to a more recent release (ideally the very latest). This is particularly true if you're going to be using partitioning.

I certainly would not recommend you get into the habit of rewriting joins using `$PARTITION`, except as a very last resort, and with a very deep understanding of what you are doing.

That's about all I can say without being able to see the schema or plan detail.